# About python OS Package

Tags: python, python3

I wrote 3 simple lines, this opens a new terminal and executes the following code.

```
import os        
os.system("gnome-terminal -x airodump-ng wlan0mon")
```

But when I press ctrl + c, the new terminal instantly closes.
I don't want the terminal to close.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'YOUR COMMAND; bash'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'airodump-ng wlan0mon; bash' ")`
```